# Accessing selected object attributes in form in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have few select inputs in `@Page` and besides storing value of selected option, like `{{project.title}}`, I also need to return another selected object property, like `{{project.id}}` or whole object.

If I use for ex. `(change)='DoThing($event)'`, it returns just string with `project.title`. I can't put `{{object.id}}`, it generates runtime error.

Code I use:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Project</ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrackedTime.project" (change)='DoThing()'>
           <ion-option *ngFor='#project of myProjects' value="{{project.title}}">{{project.title}}</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I'm sure this should work somehow, but after consulting few ANG2 Form Tutorials, I'm not clear how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: When I put {{project.id}} in (change)='DoThing()':

`browser_adapter.ts:73 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 8 in [DoThing({{project.id}})] in ModalAddtimePage@14:57 ("em>
      <ion-label>Project</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrackedTime.project" [ERROR ->](change)='DoThing({{project.id}})'>
                  <ion-option *ngFor='#project of myProjects' va"): ModalAddtimePage@14:57`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you can't refer to one item created by `*ngFor` from outside `*ngFor` is expected.

You can use `project.title` which you get from `$event` to look up the project from `myProjects`. I guess it would be better to assign `id` to `value`

```
value="{{project.id}}"
```

then you get the `project.id` from `$event`.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Project</ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrackedTime.project" (change)='DoThing($event)'>
           <ion-option *ngFor='#project of myProjects' value="{{project.id}}">{{project.title}}</ion-option>
       </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

...

```
DoThing(id) {
  let project = this.myProjects.find((prj) => { return prj.id == id; });
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="newTrackedTime.project" (change)='DoThing()'>
  <ion-option *ngFor='#project of myProjects' 
    [attr.value]="project.title">{{project.title}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**Edit**

Your error says that you use this:

```
(change)='DoThing({{project.id}})'
```

but `project` is only usable at the level of the `ngFor` in options...

Comment: Thanks for explaining that error, I wish there was some translator :)

Answer (score 0):

give a name to your `ion-select` and pass it to `DoThing()`:

```
<ion-select name="selectTime" [(ngModel)]="newTrackedTime.project" (change)='DoThing(selectTime)'>
```

you will get the whole select DOM object,and you can explore its children to find the checked one and its attributes

Comment: this is a bit complicated solution, but thanks anyway!